# Using Enterprise Library Logging to log to Azure SQL?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to get Enterprise Library 5.0 logging to log to Azure SQL. I think my .config is ok but I'm trying to setup the SQL tables and stored procs using the scripts that come with EntLib 5.0 (`\EntLib50Src\Blocks\Logging\Src\DatabaseTraceListener\Scripts\`)

Since the script is pretty long, I've [uploaded it here](http://pastebin.com/4T4GURPr) (vs embedding it in question)

Unfortunately, that script was written by the EntLib team in 2005 and was never updated or maintained. Subsiquently, many of the commands don't work against Azure SQL or even SQL Server 2012. The error I get on SQL Server 2012 is

`Could not find stored procedure 'sp_dboption'.`

Is there an updated script for setting up the tables and stored procedures for Azure SQL? Also, if you're logging on Azure SQL, would appreciate you sharing your script.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the script is not maintained; the script is for SQL Server and works with all versions of SQL Server that were tested against for the last release of Enterprise Library (May 2011). Version 6 is in the planning stages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was :

1. [Downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027). This is a must have if you're managing any Azure SQL database. It's great with Schema compare and merging changes as well as being able to push into GIT with the rest of your code. Anyways, back to topic ...
2. Added a "SQL Server Database project" to my solution.
3. "Right click the database project => properties => set target to "Windows Azure SQL Database". Also checked "Create script" in the output types area in the same section.
4. Right click database project => Import SQL => pass it the EntLib5.0 script from 2005. This breaks the script into separate .SQL files for each table and each stored procedure.
5. Visual Studio complained that the entire script can't be broken down (mostly the stored procs). What it was able to import is commented out in the imported script (good, prevents duplicates)
6. I manually added the stored procs. Add new item => stored proc => use name seen inside the 2005 script => copy-paste the same old SQL code. Did this for all the 4 SP's in the 2005 SQL script file
7. "Built" the project => no errors
8. Right click database project => schema compare => point to your azure database
9. Click update

Clicking update will automatcally create the SQL script and it'll run it against the Azure database. The script generated is below. For some reason the same script wouldn't run properly in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio (yes, even with SQL CMD mode on). Howeven running it from the VS2012 data project (above) worked just fine.

```
/*
Deployment script for test

This code was generated by a tool.
Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
the code is regenerated.
*/

GO
SET ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, ARITHABORT, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;


GO
:setvar DatabaseName "Logging"
:setvar DefaultFilePrefix "Logging"
:setvar DefaultDataPath ""
:setvar DefaultLogPath ""

GO
:on error exit
GO
/*
Detect SQLCMD mode and disable script execution if SQLCMD mode is not supported.
To re-enable the script after enabling SQLCMD mode, execute the following:
SET NOEXEC OFF; 
*/
:setvar __IsSqlCmdEnabled "True"
GO
IF N'$(__IsSqlCmdEnabled)' NOT LIKE N'True'
    BEGIN
        PRINT N'SQLCMD mode must be enabled to successfully execute this script.';
        SET NOEXEC ON;
    END


GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[Category]...';


GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category] (
    [CategoryID]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] NVARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CategoryID] ASC)
);


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[CategoryLog]...';


GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoryLog] (
    [CategoryLogID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID]    INT NOT NULL,
    [LogID]         INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CategoryLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CategoryLogID] ASC)
);


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[CategoryLog].[ixCategoryLog]...';


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ixCategoryLog]
    ON [dbo].[CategoryLog]([LogID] ASC, [CategoryID] ASC);


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[Log]...';


GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log] (
    [LogID]            INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [EventID]          INT             NULL,
    [Priority]         INT             NOT NULL,
    [Severity]         NVARCHAR (32)   NOT NULL,
    [Title]            NVARCHAR (256)  NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp]        DATETIME        NOT NULL,
    [MachineName]      NVARCHAR (32)   NOT NULL,
    [AppDomainName]    NVARCHAR (512)  NOT NULL,
    [ProcessID]        NVARCHAR (256)  NOT NULL,
    [ProcessName]      NVARCHAR (512)  NOT NULL,
    [ThreadName]       NVARCHAR (512)  NULL,
    [Win32ThreadId]    NVARCHAR (128)  NULL,
    [Message]          NVARCHAR (1500) NULL,
    [FormattedMessage] NTEXT           NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LogID] ASC)
);


GO
PRINT N'Creating FK_CategoryLog_Category...';


GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoryLog] WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoryLog_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([CategoryID]);


GO
PRINT N'Creating FK_CategoryLog_Log...';


GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoryLog] WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoryLog_Log] FOREIGN KEY ([LogID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Log] ([LogID]);


GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[ClearLogs]...';


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE ClearLogs
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM CategoryLog
    DELETE FROM [Log]
    DELETE FROM Category
END
GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[InsertCategoryLog]...';


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCategoryLog
    @CategoryID INT,
    @LogID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CatLogID INT
    SELECT @CatLogID FROM CategoryLog WHERE CategoryID=@CategoryID and LogID = @LogID
    IF @CatLogID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO CategoryLog (CategoryID, LogID) VALUES(@CategoryID, @LogID)
        RETURN @@IDENTITY
    END
    ELSE RETURN @CatLogID
END
GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[WriteLog]...';


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[WriteLog]
(
    @EventID int, 
    @Priority int, 
    @Severity nvarchar(32), 
    @Title nvarchar(256), 
    @Timestamp datetime,
    @MachineName nvarchar(32), 
    @AppDomainName nvarchar(512),
    @ProcessID nvarchar(256),
    @ProcessName nvarchar(512),
    @ThreadName nvarchar(512),
    @Win32ThreadId nvarchar(128),
    @Message nvarchar(1500),
    @FormattedMessage ntext,
    @LogID int OUTPUT
)
AS 

    INSERT INTO [Log] (
        EventID,
        Priority,
        Severity,
        Title,
        [Timestamp],
        MachineName,
        AppDomainName,
        ProcessID,
        ProcessName,
        ThreadName,
        Win32ThreadId,
        Message,
        FormattedMessage
    )
    VALUES (
        @EventID, 
        @Priority, 
        @Severity, 
        @Title, 
        @Timestamp,
        @MachineName, 
        @AppDomainName,
        @ProcessID,
        @ProcessName,
        @ThreadName,
        @Win32ThreadId,
        @Message,
        @FormattedMessage)

SET @LogID = @@IDENTITY
RETURN @LogID
GO
PRINT N'Creating [dbo].[AddCategory]...';


GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddCategory]
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @CategoryName nvarchar(64),
    @LogID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @CatID INT
    SELECT @CatID = CategoryID FROM Category WHERE CategoryName = @CategoryName
    IF @CatID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Category (CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)
        SELECT @CatID = @@IDENTITY
    END

    EXEC InsertCategoryLog @CatID, @LogID 

    RETURN @CatID
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the formally correct answer is to download the EnterpriseLibraryIntegrationPack-WindowsAzure-sqlscripts.exe from [Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0 Integration Pack for Windows Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28189).  When unpacked this contains all of the SQL scripts required for Enterprise Library modified by the Patterns & Practices team to work with SQL Azure.

I'm leaving my original answer below because it is virtually identical to the script provided.

The script provided for Database Logging is for SQL Server.  [SQL Azure does not support the sp_dboption stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336237.aspx).

Basically, all you really need are the Category, CategoryLog, and Log tables along with the AddCategory, WriteLog, and InsertCategoryLog stored procedures.

First create the Logging database (either using the portal or by running a script):

```
CREATE DATABASE [Logging]
(MAXSIZE=1GB,
EDITION='web');
GO
```

If you remove the unsupported statements the script would look something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Category]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category](
    [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryName] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryID] ASC
) 
) 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CategoryLog]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CategoryLog](
    [CategoryLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LogID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CategoryLog] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryLogID] ASC
) 
) 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Log]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [LogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventID] [int] NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Severity] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [MachineName] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [AppDomainName] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [ProcessID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ProcessName] [nvarchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [ThreadName] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [Win32ThreadId] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](1500) NULL,
    [FormattedMessage] [ntext] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LogID] ASC
) 
) 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[InsertCategoryLog]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE InsertCategoryLog
    @CategoryID INT,
    @LogID INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CatLogID INT
    SELECT @CatLogID FROM CategoryLog WHERE CategoryID=@CategoryID and LogID = @LogID
    IF @CatLogID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO CategoryLog (CategoryID, LogID) VALUES(@CategoryID, @LogID)
        RETURN @@IDENTITY
    END
    ELSE RETURN @CatLogID
END
' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AddCategory]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddCategory]
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @CategoryName nvarchar(64),
    @LogID int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @CatID INT
    SELECT @CatID = CategoryID FROM Category WHERE CategoryName = @CategoryName
    IF @CatID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Category (CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)
        SELECT @CatID = @@IDENTITY
    END

    EXEC InsertCategoryLog @CatID, @LogID 

    RETURN @CatID
END

' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[ClearLogs]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE ClearLogs
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM CategoryLog
    DELETE FROM [Log]
    DELETE FROM Category
END
' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[WriteLog]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'



/****** Object:  Stored Procedure dbo.WriteLog    Script Date: 10/1/2004 3:16:36 PM ******/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[WriteLog]
(
    @EventID int, 
    @Priority int, 
    @Severity nvarchar(32), 
    @Title nvarchar(256), 
    @Timestamp datetime,
    @MachineName nvarchar(32), 
    @AppDomainName nvarchar(512),
    @ProcessID nvarchar(256),
    @ProcessName nvarchar(512),
    @ThreadName nvarchar(512),
    @Win32ThreadId nvarchar(128),
    @Message nvarchar(1500),
    @FormattedMessage ntext,
    @LogId int OUTPUT
)
AS 

    INSERT INTO [Log] (
        EventID,
        Priority,
        Severity,
        Title,
        [Timestamp],
        MachineName,
        AppDomainName,
        ProcessID,
        ProcessName,
        ThreadName,
        Win32ThreadId,
        Message,
        FormattedMessage
    )
    VALUES (
        @EventID, 
        @Priority, 
        @Severity, 
        @Title, 
        @Timestamp,
        @MachineName, 
        @AppDomainName,
        @ProcessID,
        @ProcessName,
        @ThreadName,
        @Win32ThreadId,
        @Message,
        @FormattedMessage)

    SET @LogID = @@IDENTITY
    RETURN @LogID



' 
END
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'FK_CategoryLog_Category') AND parent_obj = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CategoryLog]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoryLog]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoryLog_Category] FOREIGN KEY(  [CategoryID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] (   [CategoryID])
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'FK_CategoryLog_Log') AND parent_obj = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CategoryLog]'))
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoryLog]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CategoryLog_Log] FOREIGN KEY(   [LogID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Log] (    [LogID])
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
SET ARITHABORT ON 
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON 
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF 
go

DECLARE @bErrors as bit

BEGIN TRANSACTION
SET @bErrors = 0

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ixCategoryLog] ON [dbo].[CategoryLog] ([LogID] ASC, [CategoryID] ASC )
IF( @@error <> 0 ) SET @bErrors = 1

IF( @bErrors = 0 )
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
ELSE
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

I then used SSMS as per [Managing Windows Azure SQL Database using SQL Server Management Studio](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/sql-azure-management/) to run the script.